# Retrieve value from a dynamically created textbox - jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox

Fellas,

I am creating a text box dynamically, on a button click. User types a value in it. Now, how do I extract the value from the text box? I've tried with .keyup() and .change() but cant get it to work. Ive spent hours now. Is there any help out there?

The button html code -

```
<input type="button" value="Verify" id="addButton" class="verifybtn">
```

JQuery for creating the text box on the fly and then trying to read the value entered -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ctr=0;
$("#addButton").click(function () {

    if ( ctr < 1 ){
    $('.verifybtn').after('<div id="TextBoxDiv1"><label>Enter Verification Code : </label><input type="textbox" size=5 id="textbox1" class="textbox1"></div>');
id="textbox1" class="textbox1">');
    ctr++;
    }
});

$("#textbox1").keyup(function(){
    value = $("#textbox1").attr('value');   
    alert(value);
});

$("#textbox1").change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});

});
```

If you can either quickly point out what Im doing wrong, or suggest alternative ways of achieving this, I shall be ever thankful.

-DM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also get it as:

```
$("#textbox1").live('keyup', function(){
    value = $("#textbox1").val();   
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: Excellent. This works. Thanks so much. I should've asked here long back. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textbox1").val();
```

Gets the value. You can also rewrite the `keyUp` handler to look like this:

```
$("#textbox1").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();   
    alert(value);
});
```

Note the `var` keyword there. You want to make sure that the `value` variable is scoped to that function and only that function.

Comment: Well, it isn't. I suspect this has something to do with the fact that the textbox gets created on the fly and does not exist when the whole form is created initially. Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".textbox1").val();
```